# How do I create a class from a text file in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

How would i create a class from a Text_file.txt containing the below data. So that A-I are my objects.

Text_file.txt format:

```
[{'A': 443582874, 'B': '015490199481', 'C': 98874007784, 'D': 'Banana', 'E': 'buy', 'F': '0.2000', 'G': '0.031076', 'H': '-0.000000621520', 'I': '2019-02-01T11:19:22.740Z'}, {'A': 443484705, 'B': '015490131470', 'C': 98848326070, 'D': 'Apple', 'E': 'sell', 'F': '0.2000', 'G': '0.030879', 'H': '-0.000000617580', 'I': '2019-02-01T09:35:09.198Z'}]
```

So that when:

```
print(class['D0']):
```

Returns:

```
Banana
```

And

```
print(class['D0':'D1'])
```

Returns:

```
Banana
Apples
```

Comment: `[D0]`…?! You mean `['D0']`…?

Comment: I think it would be `[0]['D']`

Comment: it can help you `print(data[0].get('D))` and `print([x.get('D') for x in data[0:2]])`

Comment: What have you done so far? I think magic methods such as indexing and slicing can help here but it's not clear why you would want to create such a solution.

Comment: Well, you *could* make a class that returns `[0]['D']` from the above array by accessing its `'D0'` attribute…

Comment: Why do you need a class for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a thing, but there is a way of doing it.

If instead of it being `text_file.txt` the file was `text_file.py` and the contents were something like this:

```
var = [{'A': 443582874, 'B': '015490199481', 'C': 98874007784, 'D': 'Banana', 'E': 'buy', 'F': '0.2000', 'G': '0.031076', 'H': '-0.000000621520', 'I': '2019-02-01T11:19:22.740Z'}, {'A': 443484705, 'B': '015490131470', 'C': 98848326070, 'D': 'Apple', 'E': 'sell', 'F': '0.2000', 'G': '0.030879', 'H': '-0.000000617580', 'I': '2019-02-01T09:35:09.198Z'}]
```

then in your script you had

```
from text_file import var

print(var[0]['D'])
```

that would give you `'Banana'`.

You would need `text_file.py` to be in the same folder (or at least somewhere in your path) as your python script, so that it could be imported.

I do this sometimes for configs. You are also mis-using the name `class` which isn't what this is.

---

Edit:

doing this:

```
print(class['D0':'D1'])
```

is probably possible, but I don't think it's what you want at all - to do it you would basically be rebuilding your own indexing symantics for a different data structure - why not just learn the one that python already has?

something like this:

```
print([i['D'] for i in var[0:1]])
```

would give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a Python reserved word with a special meaning, which I don't think is what you mean  here.

What you appear to have is a JSON string, which can be imported into Python as a 2-element list of dicts. Except it's using single-quotes instead of double-quotes. So read the file into `string`, then

```
import json

string = string.replace( "'", '"')
j = json.loads( string)
```

you can now refer to `j[0]['D']` and `[ x['D'] for x in j ]` (the latter is the list `['Banana', 'Apple']`